# Actor subscript can not be mutated

Tags: ios, swift, async-await

I have this actor:

```swift
public actor MyActor {
    private var array: [String] = []

    public subscript(index: Int) -> String {
        get {
            array[index]
        }
        set {
            array[index] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to use the subscript like this:

```swift
let myActor = MyActor()

Task {
    await myActor[0] = "foo" // compilation error on this line
}
```

I get this compilation error:

> Actor-isolated subscript 'subscript(_:)' can not be mutated from a non-isolated context

How can I use the subscript method on an actor?

Comment: It would not appear that you can do that. Given how often subscripts are the source of threading mistakes (i.e., the subscript operator is almost always the wrong level to be performing synchronization; you generally need a higher level of synchronization), I think that’s prudent.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting isn't specific to subscript, you can get the same error if you make `array` property public and try to set it the same way outside the actor.

This error is because unlike `get`, `set` accessor in swift doesn't support `async` specifier as of now. So when you are trying to set the property from outside the actor, the compiler is giving error as you are calling an actor isolated method synchronously outside the actor.

Your only option as of now is to create a new method to update data and call that outside of actor instead:

```swift
public actor MyActor {
    public var array: [String] = []

    public subscript(index: Int) -> String {
        get {
            array[index]
        }
        set {
            array[index] = newValue
        }
    }

    public func setItem(_ item: String, at index: Int) {
        array[index] = item
    }
}

let myActor = MyActor()

Task {
    await myActor.setItem("foo", at: 0)
}
```